# Office 360 Excel formula with output to separate cell. No code

Tags: excel, formula

Sorry if this is a old question, I have a requirement to have a value pushed from a cell on one sheet to another cell on anaother sheet, without setting the destination cell.

So: 'Sheet1!A1' has formula, 'Sheet2!A2' is where I would like the output to end up without setting the cell with ='Sheet!A1' or using VBA, otherwise we would not be here right now.

It seems like a simple ask the beginning but I'm stumped

Comment: Not clear what you wanting to do?

Comment: Sorry, I want to have cell A1 do 1+1 for example and another cell on a seperate sheet have the answer. The cell with the answer needs to be blank and i,m trying to not use code. So I want cell A1 to contain the formula that puts the answer in the other cell.

Comment: A formula can only return a value to the cell in which it is located.  It cannot "push" a value to some other cell.

Comment: AFAIK, your conditions of no code and no formula in Sheet2!A2 means that this requirement would be impossible to achieve in an automated way within Excel. As Ron said, Excel doesn't permit you to "push" a value.

If you must "push" the value, then you'll have to use code.

Comment: Thanks for the assist, I feared that this would be the case.  Back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

The cell in the other sheet cannot have the answer and also be blank. You can, however, set the colour of the text to be the same as the background.

Comment: Sorry  blank to start with. No cell ref prior to the answer ending up there.

Comment: It depends, then, on the formula you want to evaluate. It could get quite complicated. If a 1+1 or 45+24 is in Sheet1!A1 then =IF(Sheet1!A1="","",IF(MID(Sheet1!A1,IFERROR(FIND("+",Sheet1!A1),99999),1)="+",VALUE(LEFT(Sheet1!A1,FIND("+",Sheet1!A1)-1))+VALUE(MID(Sheet1!A1,FIND("+",Sheet1!A1)+1,99)),"Formula was not an addition.")) would work. Any variation of the format would fail.

Comment: There's a very simple solution if you don't mind a macro enabled sheet: 

`Function TextToFormula(FoTe As String)`
`Application.Volatile`
`TextToFormula = Evaluate(FoTe)`
`End Function`